# Как использовать typescript в React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Прошу помощи..
С объектами все довольно понятно нежели с function.

```
function identity<T>(arg: T):T { return arg }
let myIdentity: <T>(arg: T) => T = identity
```

в первой строке  ясно. <Т> это обычный  параметр. Но как понять вторую строку ? (пример из документации)
Для чего это делать? по сути мы сделали это же в объявлении function.

и второй момент касательно React это:

```
    interface Test {
     a: number;
   }

    const App: FunctionComponent<Test> = () => {
      return <div>123</div>;
    };
```

что тут вообще происходит? получаетя, что мы после App: описываем не тип function как в документации, а тип объекта ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое выражение можно написать так:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T):T { 
    return arg 
}

let myIdentity: <T>(arg: T) => T
myIdentity = identity
```

Мы явно указываем, что `myIdentity` принимает и хранит ссылку на функцию принимающую в качестве аргумента T и возвращающую T: `<T>(arg: T) => T`.

Транслятор TypeScript сможет проверить, что соблюдается контракт использования функции и переменной:

```
myIdentity(10).toFixed() // ok 

myIdentity("hello").toFixed() // Ошибка: Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type '"hello"'. Did you mean 'fixed'? 

myIdentity = (str: string)=> str.length // Ошибка: Type '(str: string) => number' is not assignable to type '<T>(arg: T) => T'
```

---

FunctionComponent где-то должен быть определен в виде интефейса или typealias.

```
type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P)=> ReactElement
```

В React в качестве компонента может быть использована [функция](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

```
var component = function(props) {
    return <div>123</div>;
}
```

Это корректное определение компонента, но тут нет проверки типов, мы можем переменной `component` присвоить все что угодно. TypeScript позволит проверить корректность присваиваемых значений:

```
let app: FunctionComponent<Test> = function (props) {
    return <div>123, {props.a}</div>; // ok
}
```

А это присвоение вызовет ошибку: `Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible`:

```
let otherApp: FunctionComponent<Test> = function (props: string) {
    return <div>123, {props}</div>;
}
```